# Concluded hearing

Tags: meaning, legalese

> They appealed against the ruling to the supreme court, which concluded hearings on the subject in March last year.

What does "concluded hearings" mean here? Does that mean "Supreme Court already gave their judgement in March last year"?

Comment: *To conclude* here means to finish.  They've finished hearing the case.  They may or may not have concluded their deliberations.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the confusion here is the word "hearing," which in the context of law, is a noun, not (closely) related to the verb "to hear." A hearing is a public meeting in a court where both sides are debated; exactly what it means depends on the court and the case up for debate. Usually a decision is not handed down at a hearing. In this case, presumably the court hands down a decision a long time after the hearing (but that's just a question about this court, not a question about the word "hearing.")

The word "conclude" here just means "terminate/finish/end" as it always does.